# Running Different Function In separete driver with Selenium Automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a Python project where I need to perform web automation tasks simultaneously on multiple web drivers using Selenium. I have separate classes with methods for interacting with TikTok and Instagram profiles. Each class contains methods like follow_tiktok, like_tiktok, follow_insta, and like_insta.

My goal is to run these methods at a same time on different web drivers to speed up the process. However, I'm not sure about the best approach to achieve this while avoiding synchronization issues and resource conflicts.

I have create separate profile for each fuction like follow_tiktok, like_tiktok, follow_insta, and like_insta.
"D:\python files selenium\Getlike_Profiles\set1\il" this is expected to run insta like
"D:\python files selenium\Getlike_Profiles\set1\if" this is expected to run insta follow
"D:\python files selenium\Getlike_Profiles\set1\tl" this is expected to run tiktok like
"D:\python files selenium\Getlike_Profiles\set1\tf" this is expected to run tiktok follow

This is my code

`class tiktok: def follow_tiktok(b): # goto next opened tab driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) time.sleep(4) if "https://www.tiktok.com/" in current_url(): check_captcha = CaptchaSolver.captcha() if (check_captcha == 2): return 2 elif (check_captcha == 1 or 3): try: verify_follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_follow']))) if verify_follow.is_displayed(): # Click follow button print("Following the Account") verify_follow.click() time.sleep(1) try: call_verify_follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_followed']))) if "Message" in call_verify_follow.text: time.sleep(1) print("Followed the account") return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return 2 except TimeoutException: try: afollowed = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_followed']))) if "Message" in afollowed.text: time.sleep(1) print("Already Followed") return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return 2 def like_tiktok(b): # goto next opened tab driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) time.sleep(3) if "https://www.tiktok.com/" in current_url(): check_captcha = CaptchaSolver.captcha() if (check_captcha == 2): return 2 elif (check_captcha == 1 or 3): try: pause = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_pp']))) print("pausing the video") pause.click() time.sleep(1) try: aliked = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_liked']))) print("Already Liked", b) time.sleep(1) return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: try: main_like = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_main_like']))) main_like.click() time.sleep(1) print("Liking the Video", b) try: chk_like = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_liked']))) if (chk_like.is_displayed()): print("Liked the Video", b) return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: try: like = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_av_like']))) like.click() print("Liking the Video", b) try: chk_like = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_tiktok['tiktok_liked']))) if (chk_like.is_displayed()): print("Liked the Video", b) return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return task_verify(b) class instagram: def follow_insta(b): # goto next opened tab driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) time.sleep(1) if "https://www.instagram.com" in current_url(): time.sleep(5) try: res_prf = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['res_prf_insta']) if res_prf.is_displayed(): print("restricted profile") return 2 except NoSuchElementException: # following the profile print("\n\nGot the Instagram Follow Task") for a in range(1, 3): try: verify_follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_follow_text'].format(a=a)))) follow_text = verify_follow.text if "Follow" == follow_text: try: # Click follow button clk_follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_follow'].format(a=a)))) if clk_follow.is_displayed(): print("Following the Account") clk_follow.click() time.sleep(4) try: call_verify_follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located( (By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_follow_text'].format(a=a)))) if "Following" == call_verify_follow.text: time.sleep(1) print("Followed the account") return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return 2 except TimeoutException: return 2 elif "Following" == follow_text: time.sleep(1) print("Already Followed") return task_verify(b) break except TimeoutException: if a == 1: continue elif a == 2: driver.close() driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) return 2 def like_insta(b): # goto next opened tab driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) time.sleep(1) if "https://www.instagram.com" in current_url(): time.sleep(5) try: verify_aliked = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_like'].format(l="Unlike")))) if (verify_aliked.is_displayed()): print("Already Liked ", b) return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: try: like = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_like'].format(l="Like")))) if (like.is_displayed()): print("Trying to like ", b) like.click() time.sleep(2) verify_liked = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpaths_insta['insta_like'].format(l="Unlike")))) if (verify_liked.is_displayed()): print("Liked ", b) time.sleep(1) return task_verify(b) except TimeoutException: return 2`

I What I've Tried:

I've set up a Python project where I've defined classes and methods for automating interactions with TikTok and Instagram profiles using Selenium. Each class contains methods like follow_tiktok, like_tiktok, follow_insta, and like_insta. I want to run these methods concurrently on separate web drivers to improve efficiency.

To achieve this, I've used the threading module to create two threads: one for TikTok operations and another for Instagram operations. Within each thread, I've initialized a separate instance of the web driver using webdriver.Chrome(), called the relevant methods for each platform, and finally, joined the threads using .join().

Expectations:

I expected the code to run the web automation methods concurrently, with TikTok and Instagram operations being performed simultaneously on separate web drivers. I hoped that this approach would help speed up the overall process of interacting with multiple profiles on both platforms.

However, since I'm relatively new to multi-threading and web automation, I'm unsure whether my approach is correct and whether there might be any synchronization or resource management issues that I should be aware of. Additionally, I'm curious if using asynchronous libraries like asyncio and aiohttp might be a better approach for managing concurrent web automation tasks.

Any guidance or insights into the correctness of my approach and potential improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Feel free to modify and expand upon this answer to better match your specific circumstances and expectations.